# Create class that intersects constructor argument typed as Object

Tags: typescript, constructor, intersection, typescript-class

I basically want my class to be any object I input, plus any additional methods declared in the class.

The Object properties could be anything and can be named anything when the class is constructed.

```js
// this is the type I want my class to be:
// the input object (T) plus the prototype methods (TestClass)
type MyClass = TestClass & T
```

If I were to imagine doing this, I would implement this the following way:

```js
class TestClass<T extends Object> {
  constructor(obj: T) {
    // this doesn't work because it wants properties after this
    // this.name, this.wife, etc.
    this = obj
  }
  returnMe(): this & T  {
    return this
  }
}

// This returns the correct type
// but the class itself doesn't have the types added on.
function TestFactory<T extends Object>(obj: T): TestClass<T> & T {
  return new TestClass(obj)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

option 1:

```
class TestClass {
  // define the methods it needs
}

function TestFactory<T extends Object>(obj: T): TestClass & T {
  return Object.assign(new TestClass(), obj)
}
```

option 2:

```
class TestClass<T extends Object> {
  // define the methods it needs
  constructor(o: T) {
    Object.assign(this, o)
  }
}

function TestFactory<T extends Object>(obj: T): TestClass<T> & T {
  return <T>new TestClass(obj)
}
```